# Page loading without action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Something really weird is happening. It's not even an error, but it's not supposed to happen.

I have a route defined:

```
get :reply
```

and I have a view defined for this route as well.

However ***I do not have a controller action setup for this route*** yet the page still loads! I've searched in my code and I just do not have another `reply` action anywhere.

I know I probably should share my code but I have no idea where to even start. This is such a weird occurrence.

Here's what I've tried:

- Restarting server
- Adding action in correct controller. I get the exact same outcome.
- I tried printing this: `<%= controller_name %>#<%= action_name %>` in my view to reveal which action it's associated with, and it gives me the correct controller and action!!! But I swear, I'm looking at the source and I don't see that action defined anywhere!

Comment: "But it's not supposed to happen." Actually, it's exactly supposed to happen. This is specifically addressed in [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action).

Comment: @jvillian Got it! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails if you have the view and route set up, it can work without the controller action. But if you define the controller action it will go through that and then the view. Also you can have a controller action without a view as long as it renders, for instance

```
def action_without_view
  ...
  render :json => ["blah"].to_json and return
  # or 
  render :text => "Yadda!" and return
end
```

"and return" tells the framework to not look for a view and simply exit upon rendering whatever it's told to.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that. I thought you always needed an action. Thanks!